# Cordova: How to save text files with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, cordova, save, saving-data

I am going to turn an array into a text file to send to a different device. I have tried doing this using plugins and libraries, but that didn't seem to work for me. I was delighted to find [this](https://robkendal.co.uk/blog/2020-04-17-saving-text-to-client-side-file-using-vanilla-js) solution that does not use any plugins or libraries. Sadly it works in my browser, but doesn't seem to work when trying it in the app itself.

The code from the website:

```
const downloadToFile = (content, filename, contentType) => {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  const file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
  
  a.href= URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = filename;
  a.click();

    URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
};

document.querySelector('#btn2').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const textArea = 'This is the text that will be in the file'  
  downloadToFile(textArea, 'data.txt', 'text/plain');
});
```

Now I'm wondering is there a way to turn this into something that would work on android?

Answer (score 0):

On Android with cordova, assuming you are using an array (my_array) as source for your file

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function (dirEntry) {
        console.log('file system open: ' + dirEntry.name);
        var isAppend = false;
        createFile(dirEntry, nombreFichero, isAppend);
    }, onErrorLoadFs);
```

And then a function to create a file:

```
function createFile(dirEntry, fileName, isAppend) {

var array_file = my_array.join("\n");
dirEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {

    //writeFile(fileEntry, null, isAppend);
    writeFile(fileEntry, array_file, isAppend);

}, onErrorCreateFile);
```

And a function to write to file:

```
function writeFile(fileEntry, dataObj, isAppend) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.onwriteend = function () {
            console.log("Successful file write..." + fileEntry.name);
        };

        fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log("Failed file read: " + e.toString());
        };

        fileWriter.write(dataObj);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately it does not seem to work for me. I think it is due to the error "cordova is not defined", I get that this occurs because the browser doesn't have the cordova.js file, but It also doesn't work in the emulator. Also added a '}' at the end of the createFile function.